# Find and replace text in bash script terminal

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, terminal, regular-expression

I have a file at `/home/count/1/details/info.txt` as follow

```
title1 {
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3
}

info {
name1 text
post1 anything
salary 1
work day1
work day2
work day3
}

work {
department sell
store ground
remarks
}

contact {
required No
}
```

Now I need to **CHANGE** above to:

```
title1 {
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3
}

info {
name1 text
post1 anything
salary 1
work day1
work day2
work day3
work day4
work day5
work day8
}

work {
department sell
store ground
remarks
Absent No
}

contact {
required No
}
```

info group has added 3 new values `work day4`, `work day5`, `work day8`.
work group got new value ie, `Absent`.

headings ie, title1, info, work are fixed and can't be changed. but values between {} are dynamically changeable and can be anything. However Key work is fixed, can only be added or removed can't be renmed.

I have to write bash file to accomplish this. only terminal with ubuntu 20.04 server minimal is available to me.

Any idea, suggest, help?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried ? Where have you found problems ?

Comment: Most of  the answers you have so far would fail if the string you want to match on (e.g. `info` or `work`) could contain a regexp metachar such as `.` or `?` and/or if the string you want to add (e.g. `Absent No`)could contain a backreference like `&` or `\1` as they're doing regexp matching and/or backreference-enabled text replacement. If any of those can happen then you should update the example in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -pi -e '
  s{^info\s*\{.*?\K(?=\})}{join "", map {"work day$_\n"} 4,5,8}mse;
  s{^work\s*\{.*?\K(?=\})}{Absent No\n}ms' /home/count/1/details/info.txt
```

Comment: +1 nice use of map for this task. perfectly excessive.

Comment: @agres In case you are wondering: Although this answer mentions perl, he is calling perl from within bash which works perfectly fine and is probably the most powerful tool for this kind of problems

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=ORS="\n\n"};
     /^info {/ { gsub("}","work day4\nwork day5\nwork day8\n}") };
     /^work {/ { gsub("}","Absent No\n}") };
     1' info.txt
```

This tells awk to read the input file a paragraph at a time (i.e. records are separated by two newlines, not just one, by setting the input record separator`RS` to `\n\n`).  It also sets the output record separator to be the same as `RS`, so that the output also has an empty line between records.

Then it uses the `gsub()` function to add extra line(s) immediately before the `}` at the end of each matching paragraph (those beginning with either "info {" or "work {").   Actually, it **replaces** the `}` at the end of those records with the extra lines **and** a `}` - which is effectively the same thing as inserting the extra lines.

The final `1` is awk shorthand for `print`, and prints each record whether it has been modified or not.

Comment: thank you very much @cas
but this prints altered text on terminal, can the file (info.txt) be updated, with this solution. then this will be accepted answer.
I tried x=awk ....; echo $x>info.txt
then all newline \n characters got lost?
thank you.

Comment: I'm not going to do **all** of your homework for you, but here's a hint: it's trivial in sh to redirect awk's output to a new file and then rename the new file over the original.

Comment: Also that script requires GNU awk for multi-char RS (due to using `RS="\n\n"` instead of `RS=""` which would work in all awks) and GNU awk has an option for updating the input file. See the man page.

Answer (score 1):

Also with `awk` in paragraph mode you can try this code:

```
awk -v s1="Absent No\n" -v s2="work day4\nwork day5\nwork day8\n"  -v OFS="\n" -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '$1 == "work" {sub(/}/, s1"&")} $1 == "info" {sub(/}/, s2"&")} 1' file
title1 {
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3
}

info {
name1 text
post1 anything
salary 1
work day1
work day2
work day3
work day4
work day5
work day8
}

work {
department sell
store ground
remarks
Absent No
}

contact {
required No
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT and doing literal string match & replacement:

```
$ awk -v RS='}\n+' -v ORS= '
    $1 == "info" { $0 = $0 "work day4\nwork day5\nwork day8\n" }
    $1 == "work" { $0 = $0 "Absent No\n" }
    { print $0 RT }
' file
title1 {
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3
}

info {
name1 text
post1 anything
salary 1
work day1
work day2
work day3
work day4
work day5
work day8
}

work {
department sell
store ground
remarks
Absent No
}

contact {
required No
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -e '
  /^info {/,/}/ s/}/work day4\nwork day5\nwork day8\n&/

  /^work {/,/}/ s/}/Absent No\n&/
' /home/count/1/details/info.txt
```

---

```
perl -i -lpe '
  /^info \{/.../}/ and /}/ && do{
  print for map { "work day$_" } 4,5,8}; 

  /^work \{/.../}/ and /}/ &&
    print "Absent No";
' /home/count/1/details/info.txt
```